# Compare arays and exclude element form one if it has duplicates in others

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I need to compare arrays, if element from first or second array has duplicates in another one I need to exclude it. I know it sound simply and I'm sure it is but i cant handle with that problem :(

So i have first array like this:

```
Array:3 [
    6 => blog/something
    4 => blog/somethingElse
    5 => blog/else
]
```

Second array almost identical:

```
Array:3 [
    1 => /blog
    2 => /comments
    3 => /posts
]
```

And the last array:

```
(integer on the left is id of elements in second array, in this example 
comments and posts)
Array:2 [
    0 => array:2 [
        'page_id' => 2
         'value'  => noindex 
    ]
    1 => array:2 [
         'page_id' => 3
         'value'  => noindex 
 ]
 ]
```

So if I have element in array first or second which exist in array thrid too AND have value = noindex i need to exclude it.

I have tried do this by foreach recursive, by array_walk_recursive but I still can't get satisfied result

Comment: How do the first two arrays correspond to the last array? Are you trying to match page_id to one of the keys in the first two arrays?

Answer (score 1):

First get all the indices you need to exclude and then exclude them:

```php
$excludeIndices = array_column(array_filter($array3, function ($entry) {
   return $entry['value'] === 'noindex';
}), 'page_id');

$keepArray1 = array_diff_key($array1, array_flip($excludeIndices));
$keepArray2 = array_diff_key($array2, array_flip($excludeIndices));
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/32d7eacb86fe21f386b74f63a6a339a4ed0bac4e)

Comment: Yes, I think it works perfectly. Thanks for help and your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can filter using the first two arrays directly.

```
$result = array_filter($last, function($item) use ($first, $second) {
    return !($item['value'] == 'noindex' &&
            (isset($first[$item['page_id']]) || isset($second[$item['page_id']]))
    );
});
```